# Why does ASLR appear to be disabled for dynamically-linked libraries on macOS?

Tags: c, macos, libc, aslr

If I'm not mistaken, the following code should print out *different* addresses every time it's run. However, it always displays the same address for `isupper` (for example).

#### Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   printf("isspace @ %p\n", dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "isspace"));
   return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
$ ./libc-simple 
isspace @ 0x7fff76b63035
$ ./libc-simple 
isspace @ 0x7fff76b63035
$ ./libc-simple 
isspace @ 0x7fff76b63035
$ ./libc-simple 
isspace @ 0x7fff76b63035
```

(I'm running macOS 10.14.6, but I tested the same code on another computer running macOS 10.15 with the same result.)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an optimization, macOS uses a shared mapping for a lot of the system libraries. They are loaded once at boot and used by all processes. For a given boot, the address is constant across all such processes. However, the address is randomized each boot for security.